# Display ‘no records’ to search results on a mysql php page

Tags: php, mysql, database, search

I would like to add the text ‘no records, please try again’ to search the search that comes up with nothing. Please be aware that I am a total beginner at this, the code I have is as following:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_REQUEST['term'])) {
    $term = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']);     
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE surname LIKE '%".$term."%' ORDER BY surname, fullname, conflictsort"; 
    $r_query = mysql_query($sql);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $initial = $row['initial'];
        $surname = $row['surname'];
        $fullname = $row['fullname'];
        $dob = $row['dob'];
        $born = $row['born'];
        $service = $row['service'];
        $enlisteddate = $row['enlisteddate'];
        $enlisted = $row['enlisted'];
        $number = $row['number'];
        $rank = $row['rank'];
        $batt = $row['batt'];
        $unit = $row['unit'];
        $section = $row['section'];
        $died = $row['died'];
        $death = $row['death'];
        $memorial = $row['memorial'];
        $conflict = $row['conflict'];
        $conflictsort = $row['conflictsort'];
        $biography = $row['biography'];
        $link = $row['link'];

        echo"<h4>$surname</h4>
        <b>Name:</b> $fullname - <b>Rank:</b> $rank ($number) - <b>Regiment:</b> $batt $unit $section
        <br /><b>Birth:</b> $dob $born
        <br /><b>Enlisted:</b> $service - $enlisteddate $enlisted
        <br /><b>Died:</b> $died $death
        <br /><b>Memorial:</b> Shown as $initial$surname at $memorial
        <br /><b>Confilct:</b> $conflict
        <br /><b><a href='$link'>$biography</a></b>
        <br /><br /><br />";
    }  
}
```

?>

Comment: wondering if you're even connecting, besides Rajdeep's answer and which api is used.

Comment: The code I have gives me a list of people on a search. I just don't know where to put the extra code Rajdeep has given me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) function to check how many rows are returned from the `SELECT` query, and display results accordingly.

```
// your code
$r_query = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($r_query)){
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query)){
        // your code
    }
}else{
    echo "no records, please try again";
}
```

---

**Sidenote**: Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. [**And this is why you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: Thanks for your help Rajeep, I don't know where to put that code. Could you please repost all my code amended with the mysqli updates.

Comment: @GrahamUK33 - He has literally already done that. You should _really_ be able to figure out how to implement this yourself. Just compare it with your own code. _Don't be lazy!_

Comment: Its not a case of being lazy, I have tried putting the code in diffrent locations and can't get it to work. I'm sure if you know what you are doing with the code then it is a very easy job to do.

Comment: @GrahamUK33 Since you're having difficultly in putting the code pieces together, here's the complete code, [http://pastebin.com/02tuei2u](http://pastebin.com/02tuei2u). However, you should go through the code and learn *how things work*, this will help you in writing your *own code* in future projects.

Comment: Thank you Rajdeep, I can see how some of the code is working, but its knowing where to place it all.

Comment: I have tried to use the same code on another search php page I have and I can't get it to work.

Comment: <?php
   if (!empty($_REQUEST['term'])) {
    $term = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']);     
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE keywords LIKE '%".$term."%'"; 
    $r_query = mysql_query($sql); 
 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r_query)){
     $id = $row['id'];
     $title = $row['title'];
     $description = $row['description'];
     $keywords = $row['keywords'];
     $link = $row['link'];

     echo"<h3><a href='$link'>$title</a></h3>$description<br /><br />";
    }
   }
  ?>

Comment: @GrahamUK33 I don't see any `mysql_num_rows()` function being used in your code. See the code snippet given in my answer and align your code accordingly. Also, please don't post the same comment multiple times.

Comment: Thank you for your help again, after adding mysql_num_rows() to the code it worked.